# Remove subfolder from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm going to create pretty links in `URL`-address.

For example I have:

```
mysite.com/language/en/
```

And remove `language` folder from `url`:

```
mysite.com/en/
```

---

I wrote in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^language/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

It's working fine, but `mysite.com/en/` should has content of `mysite.com/language/en/`. Now I have `404` error.

How can I do it?

---

**Update** (Full `.htaccess`) :

```
Options All -ExecCGI -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks

# Bad Request
ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html

# Authorization Required
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html

# Forbidden
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html

# Not found
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html

# Method Not Allowed
ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html

# Request Timed Out
ErrorDocument 408 /error/408.html

# Request URI Too Long
ErrorDocument 414 /error/414.html

# Internal Server Error
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html

# Not Implemented
ErrorDocument 501 /error/501.html

# Bad Gateway 
ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html

# Service Unavailable
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

# Gateway Timeout
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504.html

#Rewrite links
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^language/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I believe You should switch `RewriteRule`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /language/$1 [L,R]`

Comment: @BogdanKuštan After that I got `mysite.com/language*1000/en` ))

Comment: I have rules to cache content and zip it. The .htaccess is single.

Comment: Can you update the question with your full .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava did it. check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
#Rewrite links
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+language/(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!language/)(.+)$ language/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank. It works, but I have one more question: How can I denie `/language/` from `url` each time when it is.

Comment: 1st redirect rule will remove `/language/` from URL

Comment: I have one problem. Start page is getting 403 error, where is problem?

Comment: Yes, I mean it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126353/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and-anubhava).