# Remove subfolder of a folder from Url by Htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have a URL structure like this -

**https://example.com / folder / subfolder / files.html**

I have many files in the subfolder. I want to remove the 'subfolder' from the URL.

I have tried some of the StackOverflow solutions. but not succeeded.

Also please tell me where to paste the .htaccess code. in the .htaccess file which is located in 'folder' or in 'subfolder'.

## edit

**folder/htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

**subfolder/htaccesss**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+) /folder/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html-f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html[L]
```

Comment: So you want to access all your files inside `subfolder` using this version of URL `example.com/folder/file.php` ?

Comment: yes. i want like this

Comment: anyone else here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule in your `/folder/. htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

If the rule above fails to work, then use the following instead

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Remember to place the rule at the top of your htaccess or before other directives and put it in htaccess in your `/folder` directory.

EDIT :

If you also want to redirect your old URLs to the new one , for example `/folder/subfolder/file.html` to `/folder/file.html` , put the following rule in htaccess in `folder/subfolder`

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule (.+) /folder/$1 [L,R]
```

Remember to place the code above in htaccess in your `subfolder` and when you are sure the rule is working, change `R` to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent as it avoids the duplicate content issues in search engines.

Edit :

If the above solution isn't working for you, as you said in comments you are getting `404` error on redirection. The error is there because the requested file is being rewritten to a non-existent`path`/folder/file.html`. You can solve this by removing your`/folder/subfolder/. htaccess`file and only use one single htaccess in`/folder/` with the following contents :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.+)/?$ /folder/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @AlexSmith Yes , to fix stylesheet and js issues just add a base tag to the head section of your document `<base href="/">` see my answer on this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: @AlexSmith And for the redirection issue, try my updated code  and let me know how it works

Comment: @AlexSmith Since your js and CSS files are in /folder, you need to use `<base href="/folder/">` and there is no other way to fix this. You can alternatively fix your relative links , ie change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/folder/style.css">` making the links absolute but the base tag solution is easier then this.

Comment: @AlexSmith Okay try the updated code now in your `/folder/. htaccess`

Comment: i tried both the above code in folder/.htaccess and the last one redirection code in subfolder/.htaccess. The redirection is working but the target path (folder/filename) is showing 404 :/

Comment: Does the file you are requesting exist in your filesystem? @AlexSmith

Comment: yup. it exists. if it doesn't exist then how can I access it (folder/subfolder/file.html) when I remove htaccess codes .

Comment: this answer is working well without any static resources issue but not redirecting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172271/remove-subfolder-from-url  . but is it slow ? i can see regex here that's why I am asking.

Comment: @AlexSmith okay please let me check. Can you please share the htaccess file you are currently using ? (Share only the rules I suggested you to add to htaccess)

Comment: @AlexSmith I want to help fix your issues .I only have 10 minutes here so please be quick or connect with me via WhatsApp +91-96252-90054

Comment: check question..

Comment: @AlexSmith You are not using the rules I updated in my answer above. Use the updated rules rules in your `folder/. htaccess`

Comment: no matters. i took your old code from answer revisions. let me check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240633/discussion-between-alex-smith-and-amit-verma).